# Terraria: Will the Warrior, Avenger, Destroyer's Emblems and the Mechanical and Fire Gauntlets all stack?

Tags: terraria, terraria-console

I was browsing the wiki and I had the thought of making a melee beast with these items, but considering I'd need to farm the heck out of the Wall of Flesh for all of this at the very least I figured I'd ask before I invest the effort in something that might not work.

- Warrior Emblem: +15% melee dmg
- Avenger Emblem: +12% all dmg
- Destroyer Emblem: +10% all dmg, +8% crit chance
- Mechanical Glove: +12% melee dmg and melee spd
- Fire Gauntlet: +9% melee dmg and melee spd, On Fire! debuff (PvE only), increased KB

By my math, using a melee damage weapon you'd be sporting a whopping +58% melee dmg as well as +8% crit chance, +21% melee spd, +22% ranged/magic dmg, On Fire!, increased KB, and glowing weapons.

I'm sure by endgame there are much better setups to have, or depending on the circumstances you might need certain accessories more than one or more of the ones above but holy crap.  With good armor and a good weapon (maybe one with a ranged effect as well, possibly good Hardmode boomerang weapons or something like the Horseman's Blade or True Night's Edge/Terra Blade or similar weapons) this could turn you into one melee beast.

Note: I play on the 360 right now but I'm going to be getting the PC version soon (I hope) hence using both tags as I would be interested in answers for both if they are different for some reason.

Comment: In battle, you really need to be moving quick enough, so using all 5 accesory slots for damage boost isn't really a good idea.
 If you accept to free only 1 slot for mobility, I suggest you take the shroomite Hoverboard.

Comment: I totally get that, but depending on the setup you could probably work out a good multiplayer party with one dude being the Striker, while someone else Tanks and you have a good Ranger and/or Healer in the party too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The following info pertains to the PC version, though it may also pertain to the console version as well.)

The [Warrior Emblem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Warrior_Emblem), [Avenger Emblem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Avenger_Emblem), and [Destroyer Emblem](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Destroyer_Emblem) absolutely stack (quote taken from the Destroyer Emblem wiki page):

> Note that the Destroyer Emblem, Avenger Emblem, and Warrior/Ranger/Sorcerer Emblem all can be equipped simultaneously for a stacking damage bonus.

These also stack with the fire gauntlet and mechanical glove. However, consider using the [Celestial Stone](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Celestial_Stone) in place of the mechanical glove, as several of the end-game [class setups](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Class_setups) for melee builds use this accessory combination for maximum damage.

By the way, if you get the *Menacing* modifier on each accessory, it's an additional 4% damage per item! Combined with a Terra-Blade, you can rack up some ridiculous damage per hit.

Comment: I believe melee speed and critical strike chance have an important role in maximizing the DPS.

Comment: That's probably true.

Comment: Yeah the celestial stone is one of the best accessories in the game - i actually use it alongside the moon stone and sun stone so i get double its effects.

Answer (score -1):

You counted this wrong, damage modifiers stacks, but not in that way. For example if u have a +10% dmg accesory, and another one for 10% in sum up u get +21%, thats because second modifier includes the first one so it's 10% of 110% dmg = +11%

Comment: Please add sources for that

Comment: I have to agree with @Nitro.de. I can see where you are coming from entirely. A lot of people do not even consider the 10% of the original 10%. But unless you can show evidence that this particular game works that way, you are relying on speculation. While speculation can give a good answer, it can not give a definite answer, and that is what we strive for here at the Arqade. It is worth noting that with the PC version and a few hacks, this is entirely testable.

Comment: You probably wouldn't even need hacks. Find weapon with 100 damage like the Staff of the Frost Hydra and equip a bunch of % bonus accessories then see if you get more than the % summed up.